# Copy, paste, and edit multiline command in bash terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal

Commands with lots of arguments sometimes use slash escaped newlines to make them easier to read on the web. Here is a silly example

```
echo -n \
"hello" \
"world"
```

I'm not sure how to paste and edit this "properly"

Pasted into bash you get

```
$ echo -n \
> "hello" \
> "world"
```

Now if I navigate with the back arrow key on OSX, I can only edit the line with `> "world"`, not the first two lines. Usually I have to paste into a temp file to fix up a command.

Is there a better way to perform this paste which allows editing any line? `bash` setting which makes this work in a nicer way?

Comment: You need an editor which displays CR and LF and you will see that this is not possible since there is an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the paste. Put it in one line without CRLF and you won't have the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you have such a command on several lines you can, if you're using bash in emacs mode (usually the default one) `ctrl+x ctrl+e` it will open your favorite editor, as specified in your EDITOR variable.

Or you can type `fc`, this will open the editor on the last command you've typed, then you can edit it as you want, then feel free to quit, and it will be executed.

Comment: the editor shortcut is nifty. type `fc`?

Comment: It's opening an editor on the last command in your bash history, it's a bash built-in command

Comment: It seems nice for some quick prototyping, but as soon as you need to fix/edit your last command, all the formatting is gone so it's a complete mess in the end.